# C# adding textbox from nested classes

Tags: c#, forms, textbox

I've got a form, which on load instantiates another class (boxMaker) which in turn creates another (boxObj). I want the boxObj to be able to make a textbox which appears on my form.

2 questions:

It doesn't show my textbox unless I use form.controls.add(textBox); - **is that correct?**

In order for that to work, I have to pass the original form to each of the classes in turn:
Pseudo-code:

```
new boxMaker(this)
```

boxMaker creator:

```
public boxMaker (Form form)
new boxObj(form)
```

boxObj creator:

```
public boxObj (Form form)
new textbox
form.controls.add(textbox)
```

It feels REALLY clunky to have to keep passing the original object all the way down the chain:

**Is there a neater way to do it?**

Comment: Use a static Form object in your mainform then just use that object to add a textbox

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) you can also make the form1.Controls a public or even global (static) property you can access. But yes, some kind of reference is needed whether you pass it around or access it in a more direct way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the `BoxMaker` return a `TextBox`, and let the `Form` handle adding it to the `Control` list instead of passing the original `Form` around:

```
public class BoxMaker
{
    public TextBox CreateTextBox()
    {
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
        // Do Stuff
        return textBox;
    }
}
```

And use it inside your `Form` like so:

```
public class Form1
{
    public void SomeEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BoxMaker maker = new BoxMaker;
        TextBox makerMadeTextBox = maker.CreateTextBox();
        this.Controls.Add(makerMadeTextBox);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah! That makes more sense, I'm doing it backwards, passing the form down the chain, rather than letting the object come back up. Thanks!